# writing to word using python

Tags: python, winapi

I used the code below to write on ms word from a text file but its not writing the lines. Also I am not being able to set up the page width and height from it. I used wordapp.PageSetup.width to some value but it threw the error.
Please suggest where did I fail..

```
import win32com.client
read = open('out.txt','r')
curser = read.readlines()

wordapp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application") 
wordapp.Visible = 0 
x = wordapp.Documents.Add() 
x.PageSetup.Orientation = 1 # Make some Setup to the Document:
x.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 0.4
x.PageSetup.TopMargin = 0.5
x.PageSetup.Width = 8.27 #This threw an error
x.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 0.5
x.PageSetup.RightMargin = 0.4
x.Content.Font.Size = 11
x.Content.Paragraphs.TabStops.Add (100)
x.Content.Text = curser #This threw an error
x.Content.MoveEnd
x.Close() # Close the Word Document (a save-Dialog pops up)
x.Quit() # Close the Word Application
```

Comment: "An" error? You might want to detail which one.

Comment: I mean why can't I use use Content.Text = curser and why only curser[n] and how will I be able to modify the width and height of the word document..? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: And I mean why can't you just tell us ***the*** **errors** you are getting, instead of saying you got "**an** error". Thanks in advance.

Comment: AttributeError: Property '<unknown>.Width' can not be set. is what I get when I use x.PageSetup.Width= 8.27. please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Python interface uses the standard API interface for Microsoft Office applications, and so all you need to know can be found on  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835409.aspx.

A *very* quick glance reveals that the property you are looking for is not called `PageSetup.Width`, it should be [`PageSetup.PageWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197123.aspx). I did not check, but I guess your "curser" problem is the same -- `x.Content.Text` probably just does not exist as a property.

What you were doing is called "[Cargo Cult Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)" -- that is, you entered commands without really knowing what they did and did not look them up, but instead relied on other "code that worked" (I'm guessing: copied from a resource such as [The Python Script Collection](http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/view/173/192/)), repeated parts of commands that seemed relevant, and made up any missing properties as you went.

It is *not* the recommended way to learn things.

Comment: Yes I admit, I copied the code as I didn't have any useful documentation. I will study about the API for Microsoft Office to apply on my program. The problem with PageWidth is not solved yet even with your answer. however, I will try to answer this question myself.
Really appreciate your suggestion.